# Windows batch file to replace nth line with new string or extract nth line and store string in variable

Tags: batch-file

Please help me construct a Windows batch file to replace the nth line of a file. Either that, or extract the nth line and store it in a variable. This is going to be used for automatically installing Mozilla extensions.

I know how to do this with SED in Linux, but my batch skills for string manipulation are lacking.

For example, I am using this batch script to install the Mozilla Thunderbird Enigmail extension for Microsoft Windows machines:

```
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% equ x86 (
  set SOFTWARE=SOFTWARE
  set PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files       
) else (
  set SOFTWARE=SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node
  set PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files ^(x86^)
)
wget --no-check-certificate https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/downloads/file/219050/enigmail-1.5.2-tb+sm.xpi -O %TEMP%\enigmail.xpi
mkdir "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Thunderbird\extensions\enigmail"
unzip -o %TEMP%\enigmail.xpi -d "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Thunderbird\extensions\enigmail"
reg add HKLM\%SOFTWARE%\Mozilla\Thunderbird\Extensions /v enigmail@example.com ^
  /t REG_SZ /d "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Thunderbird\extensions\enigmail" /f
```

The problem I have run into is I need to update the Mozilla extension's %PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Thunderbird\extensions\enigmail\install.rdf manifest with a matching registry key to get the extension to install. The following install manifest contains more than one Mozilla ID (e.g., `<em:id>{GUID}</em:id>`).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>{daf44bf7-a45e-4450-979c-91cf07434c3d}</em:id>
    <em:version>1.0</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>

    <!-- Target Application this extension can install into, 
         with minimum and maximum supported versions. --> 
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>4.0.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>

    <!-- Front End MetaData -->
    <em:name>sample</em:name>
    <em:description>A test extension</em:description>
    <em:creator>Your Name Here</em:creator>
    <em:homepageURL>http://www.example.com/</em:homepageURL>
  </Description>      
</RDF>
```

I need to replace the first `<em:id>` of this install.rdf with `<em:id>enigmail@example.com</em:id>`. Either that, or I need to extract the first GUID "{daf44bf7-a45e-4450-979c-91cf07434c3d}" by removing the surrounding "`<em:id></em:id>`" and storing the ID along with the curly braces in a %GUID% variable and use that variable as the name of the registry key (e.g., reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Thunderbird\Extensions /v %GUID%).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension#Create_the_install_manifest for further details.

A solution for replacement or extraction of the GUID will meets my needs. It just depends on whether it is easier to extract the first GUID from the install.rdf manifest, strip away the surrounding `<em:id></em:id>` and store this {GUID} in a %GUID% variable, or replace the first GUID with the `<em:id>enigmail@example.com</em:id>` ID format.

Comment: Use "FOR /F %%L IN (filename) DO (...)". In body - increment line-counter on each step, on 7th line - echo and break/exit

Comment: Just take GNU sed for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "guid="
FOR /f "tokens=2delims=<> " %%i IN ('find/i "<em:id>" ^<q19063900.rdf') DO SET guid=%%i&GOTO useguid
:useguid
ECHO guid found=%guid%
GOTO :EOF
```

This should extract the GUID string from whichever is the first line containing `<en:id>`.

`%guid%` can then be used within your batch as you propose. Obviously, if the batch falls through the `FOR`, `%guid%` will not be set meaning no `<em:id>` found.

(`q19063900.rdf` is the name of your source `.rdf` file)

Answer (score 2):

solution with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm), for the 7th line:

```
sed  -i.bak "7 s#.*#<em:id>enigmail@example.com</em:id>#" file.html
```

---

and for the pattern `<em:id>{daf44bf7-a45e-4450-979c-91cf07434c3d}</em:id>`:

```
sed  -i.bak "7 s#<em:id>{daf44bf7-a45e-4450-979c-91cf07434c3d}</em:id>#<em:id>enigmail@example.com</em:id>#" file.html
```

Comment: with the `-i` parameter sed works as 'in-place-editor' and writes changes back to the input file. With `-i.bak` it makes a backup copy with the additional extension `.bak`. Nothing is printed to STDOUT.

Comment: +1  It works fine Endoro. Thanks for the explanation - I removed my comment.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I modified the Batch program below to show the two solutions as individual methods:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Extract GUID part of 7th line and use it in the registry key
for /F "skip=6 tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" install.rdf') do set "line7=%%b" & goto continue
:continue
set "GUID=%line7:*>=%"
set "GUID=%GUID:~0,-8%"
ECHO reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Thunderbird\Extensions /v %GUID%

rem Replace 7th line
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" install.rdf') do (
   if "%%a" neq "7" (
      echo(%%b
   ) else (
      echo     ^<em:id^>enigmail@example.com^</em:id^>
   )
)) > install.tmp
move /Y install.tmp install.rdf > NUL
```

For example:

```
> test
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Thunderbird\Extensions /v {daf44bf7-a45e-4450-979c-91cf07434c3d}

> type install.rdf
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>enigmail@example.com</em:id>
    <em:version>1.0</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>

    <!-- Target Application this extension can install into,
         with minimum and maximum supported versions. -->
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>4.0.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>

    <!-- Front End MetaData -->
    <em:name>sample</em:name>
    <em:description>A test extension</em:description>
    <em:creator>Your Name Here</em:creator>
    <em:homepageURL>http://www.example.com/</em:homepageURL>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```